# SQL Server VM keeps losing connection to Domain (DNS Issue)

Tags: windows-server-2012, dns-zone, netlogon

I have a Virtual Domain setup under VMware with 1 DC, 2 IIS Servers and 1 SQL Server.

All running Server 2012.

On the SQL Server I randomly get `The system failed to register host (A or AAAA) resource records (RRs) for network adapter` - Event ID 1028.

And
`This computer was not able to set up a secure session with a domain controller in domain` Event ID 5719

When this happens I cannot ping the Domain Controller or Register DNS.

(The system failed to register pointer (PTR) resource records (RRs) for network adapter)

If I restart the DNS Service and Netlogon service everything works well again.

It usually works all okay for about 2 hours and then loses the connection. This server is vital for our databases which is used by the IIS server. And we cannot go live as a company using the new infrastructure until this annoying issue is resolved.

Any ideas regarding this?

Many Thanks

Comment: What servers are listed as DNS servers on the SQL server?

Comment: `I have a Virtual Domain setup under VMware` - VMware what? VMware is a company. What VMware product are you using? What do all of the servers use for DNS? What does the Domain Controller use for DNS?

Comment: Sorry i should have been more specific. Using EXSi 6.

Comment: All the servers use the Domain Controller as the DNS. The Domain Controller is defined as the DNS server.

The SQL Server has only listed the Domain Controller as DNS.

So before I went home yesterday evening everything was working fine. This morning I'm seeing Group Policy erros.

'The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows could not obtain the name of a domain controller. This could be caused by a name resolution failure. Verify your Domain Name System (DNS) is configured and working correctly'

Comment: What does the Domain Controller use for DNS?

Comment: The DC uses it self as the DNS server.

Comment: Any other ideas?